# How to format date and time in XAML in Xamarin application

Tags: datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a set up XAML code below.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Date}"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding Time}'}"></Label>
```

I want result like september 12,2014 2:30 PM.

Comment: Looks as though you've fogotten to add your xaml code!

Comment: The answers below are probably closer to what you are looking for, but you should note that Xamarin Forms has a bug in regards to the formatting of dates in binding. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/290295/#Comment_290295

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper I saw your thread and issue was moved to GitHub. Thank you very much for you contribution. Unfortunately, as of today, it is still not solved. I will just leave a link to the GitHub- Issue here so people can be up to date.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2049

Answer (score 180):

Change your code to:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{}{0:hh\\:mm}'}"></Label>
```

Comment: Googled this and found my own answer. First two answers are useless  but this one solves it. Good job me!

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. This should be accepted answer...

Answer (score 13):

Make a custom IValueConverter implementation:

```net
public class DatetimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter implementation

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var datetime = (DateTime)value;
        //put your custom formatting here
        return datetime.ToLocalTime().ToString("g");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then use it like that:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:DatetimeToStringConverter x:Key="cnvDateTimeConverter"></local:DatetimeToStringConverter>
</ResourceDictionary>

...

<Label Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource cnvDateTimeConverter}}"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource cnvDateTimeConverter}}"></Label>
```

Comment: I try your code, but getting invalid cast exception on the line,    var datetime = (DateTime)value; For me receiving the date as a java timestamp: 1510822596449. Is your code working for fine for converting java timestamp to string date?

Comment: Me too, i tried your code then i got a invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 10):

```
<Label>

<Label.FormattedText>

<FormattedString>

<Span Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"/>
<Span Text=" "/>
<Span Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{0:h:mm tt}'}"/>

</FormattedString>

</Label.FormattedText>

</Label>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the standard [.NET Date Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifiers.

To get

> September 12, 2014 2:30 PM

use something like

```
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
```

Comment: Date is binding as expected but  **time** is not , it only displays 2: 30 but not 2:30 PM where time is a TimeSpan

Comment: a TimeSpan represents an *interval* - it does not have a concept of AM/PM

Comment: Can you provide the XAML please